# Differentiability of the function $x^{n+\frac{1}{2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

How can I prove that the function $x^{n+\frac{1}{2}}$ is differentiable?

Do I split it up into $x^n$ and $x^{\frac{1}{2}}$? Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Find the derivative. If the derivative exists, then the function is differentiable.

Comment: Is there any way to do that without finding the derivative?

Comment: It really depends on what prior results you are allowed to use. If you have the formula to differentiate $x^r$ for any real constant $r \neq -1,$ then it's trivial. If you have this only for integer values of $r$ and for $r = \frac12,$ then your own suggestion is a good one. Give us a clue what we have available to work with?

Comment: Questions states to use the Product Rule, and that the derivative on x^n is nx^(n-1) to show that f=x^n+1/2 is differentiable. Important to note that n is the positive integers

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) = x^{n+\frac{1}{2}} = x^{\frac{2n+1}{2}}$, and let $a$ be fixed, we have:

$f'(a) = \displaystyle \lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{f(a+h) - f(a)}{h} = \displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{\sqrt{(a+h)^{2n+1}} - \sqrt{a^{2n+1}}}{h} = \displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0}\left[\dfrac{(a+h)^{2n+1} - a^{2n+1}}{h}\cdot \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{(a+h)^{2n+1}}+\sqrt{a^{2n+1}}}\right] =\dfrac{(2n+1)a^{2n}}{2\sqrt{a^{2n+1}}} = \dfrac{2n+1}{2}\cdot a^{\frac{2n-1}{2}}$.

Answer (score 1):

To see that $f(x) = x^{n+\frac{1}{2}}$ is differentiable, it suffices to show that

$$ \lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} $$

exists.

However, if you are allowed to use the fact that $x^n$ and $x^\frac{1}{2}$ are differentiable, then you could appeal to the product rule to show that $x^{n+\frac{1}{2}} = x^n x^\frac{1}{2}$ is indeed differentiable.